# More transmit power for 433MHz transmitter module by increasing voltage

Tags: arduino, wireless, 433mhz

I am using [these](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/433Mhz-RF-link-kit-p-127.html?cPath=139_140) 433MHz modules. According to the product information, I can supply the transmitter from 3-12 Volts. I am sending the data from an arduino (5V data) and want to power the transmitter with 12V that I am still be able to receive the data some meters away from the transmitter.

Can the transmitter still determine if it was a high or a low, when it is powered with 12V and the max data voltage is 5V or do I need a driver circuit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old question but still relevant and high in google results.

Just connect your 5V data output to the data input of your emitter and the 12V from your power supply to the VCC of your emitter. I've done it and it works.

Comment: With the specs only consisting of 5 lines if text in a wiki, first hand experience is the only way to tell if it works (assuming it will will work again if it did once).

Answer (score 2):

The device is basically a TX433 rebranded by a few folk and although the data sheet doesn't explicitly indicate one way or the other, [page 2](http://store.qkits.com/moreinfo.cfm/TX433.pdf) shows it connected to a HT-12E encoder (also running from 12 V) and it could be presumed that the data from the encoder is 12Vp-p: -

[image]

Here is the [HT-12E](http://www.holtek.com/pdf/consumer/2_12ev120.pdf) spec and the logic input levels are stated as related to Vcc so it's a reasonable assumption that the output levels are also related to Vcc.

Conclusion - you'll need a small driver circuit to convert from 5V logic to 12Vp-p. Maybe something like this: -

[image]

Comment: I have laying around some mosfets I power LEDs with. bit they are huge and extremly overdimensioned. What ICs do I need to convert (two-way would also be good, than I can also drive the receiver with 12V)

Comment: Would a Max662A do the job? http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX662A.pdf

Comment: Probably not - you need an N channel mosfet (or NPN transistor) as a common source/emitter level shifter.

Comment: What do I need to search for - or can you supply an example circuit? What specs would it need to have?

Comment: @Tobi - I've added a circuit that should work but it inverts so you need to logically invert the output from your MCU.

Comment: ok, but why not using an PNP and switching 12V and GND?

Comment: @Tobi you need to do some research on this and possibly present a cicruit if you are confident about it but, as far as I know the PNP would have to have its emitter at 12v and a 5V logic drive will not be able to turn said PNP transistor off. Even if collector was to ground, the emitter voltage would still be 5Vp-p. Use an NPN dude or an N channel MOSFET.

Comment: hmm, will it be possible to daisy chain this circuit and use two transistors/MOSFETs? So using the output from ciruit 1 as input from circuit 2? Output=!(!(Input) => Output = Input

I am relying to rcswitch library and virtualwire library functions and do not want to hook the library.

Comment: @Tobi you could do that if you want to avoid the inversion.

Comment: I have found something called "Darlington Transistor" looks like it is the circuit, I described: http://www.elektronik-kompendium.de/sites/slt/0411221.htm

Comment: will the following circuit work? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/104434/amplify-c-output-from-5v-to-12v-for-external-ic-that-needs-12v-to-control-witho

Comment: @Tobi it does look like it might and it's one transistor!!!

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit more info about the receiver if you scroll down the page you linked. It says that the receiver will produce a HIGH signal that is half Vcc, so if you power your receiver with 12V, then you'll get 6V for HIGH signal.

Unfortunately nothing is said of the transmitter input HIGH signal levels in that page.

The only way of knowing is to ask the vendor or to test it. One could imply the same signal level for the transmitter, but that's not healthy.

I copy the specs below.

> Basic Specification:
>
> - Frequency: 433Mhz.
> - Modulation: ASK
> - Receiver data output: High - 1/2 Vcc, Low - 0.7v
> - Transmitor input voltage: 3-12V (high voltage = more transmitting power)
> - Transmitting range (work at 5V): 40m indoor, and 100m in open air

Comment: so i will need some kind of driver circuit?

Comment: will the receiver have better receiving power, when I drive it with 12V? If so, it would solve another problem.

Comment: There, I edited and fixed my answer. But I don't have a definite answer to your question anymore, sorry. Andy aka seems to have made further inferences using the transmitter datasheet. That may help you further.

Comment: Well, I've used similar receiver modules before and I'm pretty sure that **the receiver supports 5V input supply ONLY!** Watch out or you will burn the thing.

Comment: But again, the spec seems to tie the receiver data output level to Vcc which implies it takes a range as its input supply. Well, these specs are really confusing. Sorry I can't help you further.

Answer (score 1):

The receiver will only work on 5V - think about it - why would a higher voltage help it receive more!  On the other hand the transmitter WILL give more power at 12v and I had no problems continuing to supply it data from a 5v Arduino-type-chip.  The range almost doubled. I'm using a 17cm wire on the transmitter and nothing on the receiver. [Here's a blog](http://scargill.wordpress.com/2014/06/24/radio-remote-decoding/) I wrote on the subject.  Forget the 40m indoors - that only works if your walls are made of paper. With a cottage and stone walls I reckon half of that.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Peter. The original poster (OP) is actually asking if he will be able to send data using the Arduino 5V logic HIGH if he powers the transmitter with 12V. The answer is actually NO, because the transmitter logic level threshold for logic HIGH is 12V/2, or 6V. He won't be able to give a logic HIGH to the transmitter data pin with 5V from the Arduino output. See Andy's answer and mine in which we try to explain the issue. But I also got confused with the question and started the same way you did. You can see that in my answer edit history.

Comment: Nice blog post, by the way. +1

Comment: Yeah pretty nice blog, just read it all.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is asked very often and it's not easy to find clear answers from internet (well, there are, but there is also just as much misinformation,) I feel that I should write here my findings - even though the original post is quite "oldish."

The OP's link about the device is not working anymore, so I'm *assuming* we are talking about the very cheap Chinese module labeled FS1000A (I have that silk screened on the PCB.)

If you have some other module, then the following most likely won't apply.

First thing to note is the incorrect silkscreen printing on at least the modules I have. They have data in and Vcc mixed. It works as printed, but then the Vcc goes to the modulator transistor base via 10k resistor (27k on some modules) and just saturates it and lets the oscillator/TX transistor run all the time when it gets some supply. However, the data line from your microcontroller goes to where the Vcc *should have* gone and modulates the oscillator by switching the power on/off. That "kinda" works. The "power" your transmitter will get will be no more what your controller data pin can supply. Of course, at least Arduino type controllers can supply some current from data pin (LEDs light up) but one can't expect it to be a proper supply for the transmitter.

The circuit works (if it was labeled correctly) by letting the Vcc (yes also 12V works without level shifting,  I'll getting to why soon) stay on the RF oscillator all the time and its emitter should be 'keyed' by the modulator transistor.

The modulator transistor has its emitter connected to ground and its base is connected to data (again *if* it was labelled properly) via the SMD resistor on the PCB so it'll (meaning the modulator/keying transistor) open and close just fine by quite broad range of different logic voltage levels (it's kind of a level shifter by nature) and may also work just fine even with as low as 3V3 levels. I have NOT tested 3V3 levels myself though. (Adding a level shifter would reverse the data signal polarity. One would need another transistor to flip it back or compensate the flip in software. It may raise the output power a bit if the module is being wired by wrong labels as it may give more voltage to RF transistor, depending on the level shifter's pull up resistor value. Even then you are limiting the output power with the pull up resistor and circuit-wise it's just stupid to connect the module like that. Don't do it.

Also the 'Ant' label is slightly wrong on my modules. It goes straight to the collector of the oscillator/transmit transistor and skips the output capacitor. That doesn't affect the transmitter very much otherwise, but one should keep in mind that the module voltage has a straight DC path to the antenna if the antenna touches ground.

At first glance it may look like the (again, on the modules I have) the shorter 3 turn coil is missing (compared to some images I've seen on the internet) but I had an SMD version of the coil on the solder side of the PCB. The 'Ant' label shows the hole where the collector-side of the non-SMD version of the coil can be inserted.

By raising the voltage of that mislabeled (as Vcc) data pin will give no rise to output power. It'll push already the saturated and fully conducting modulator transistor deeper into saturation.

Connecting the circuit the right way around, the microcontroller/datasource output needs to be connected to the pin that has a single PCB trace going into a single SMD resistor - nowhere else- and the data source ground to module ground. Then the +12V supply to pin where the PCB trace is going eg. to 8 turn coil and the supply ground also to module ground. That way you should be getting more power. (Twice the voltage raises the power by 4 times if all the other parameters will stay the same - which they will not.)

I don't have one of my modules right now, but if my memory serves me right, the middle pin was the correct pin for the Vcc. Gnd was labeled correctly which leaves the remaining pin for the data.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm JRE's note about the Vcc and Data inputs to the ASK transmitter being incorrectly labeled.  I had been struggling with a Tx/Rx pair for days, trying to figure out why, even with 17.3 cm dipoles, I couldn't get better than about 5 feet transmission range.  For my application, I just need good reliable message transmission with a room, so say about 20 feet.  Swapping those connections and I was suddenly out the door, down the hall, and through walls, and still getting 100% solid reception.  This mislabeling is insidious, because the transmitter "works", just poorly.

I can also confirm that powering the transmitter on 12v, but driving the data input from a 5v Arduino pin works, without buffering it through a transistor to raise its voltage.

Since people keep bringing this up, the 5v logic "high" that comes out of the Arduino pin has nothing to do with what voltage you need to feed into the transmitter's data pin to make it output a pulse.   The Vcc to the transmitter goes to a transistor's collector.  The Arduino's output goes to the base.  All the Arduino's pin needs to do is be high enough to switch on the transistor.  It doesn't need to be 1/2 Vcc.  I have now successfully tested one of these FS1000A's with an 18v supply, still driving the 5v data pin of an Arduino.  It works perfectly, and the range goes up even more than at 9v or 12v.  The data sheets on the transistors used on this board show all lowest max collector voltages to be 20v.  Perhaps it's "gutsy" pushing them to 18, but it worked great.

My transmitter is the "FS1000A" labeled one.

Answer (score -5):

then 9v supply to transmitter would a compromised solution? 9v/2 = 4.5v. So, Arduino can use 5V to make it HIGH.