# Can I use a CC1101 to read communication from an FS1000A transmitter?

Tags: rf

I would like to use a [CC1101 Low-Power Sub-1 GHz RF Transceiver](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc1101.pdf) as a receiver in one device and use an FS1000A transmitter in another device.

How do I set up the CC1101 to recognize the FS1000A transmission?

I'm using Arduino Nano boards  and [ELECHOUSE_CC1101.h](https://github.com/simonmonk/CC1101_arduino/blob/master/ELECHOUSE_CC1101.h) library.

Comment: what's  a CC1101? ... what's a FS1000A? ... people will not waste their time looking for datasheets ... please add info to your post, not in a comment

Answer (score 2):

I can't seem to find a manufacturers datasheet for the FS1000A transmitter module, but only pages from sellers such as [FS1000A 433mHz Transmitter Receiver RF Radio Module](https://www.electronicscomp.com/fs1000a-433mhz-transmitter-receiver-rf-radio-module) which says under *Transmitter Module Specification*:

- Operating frequency: 433.92MHz; 315Mhz
- Transfer rate: <10Kbps
- Modulation mode: OOK (Amplitude Modulation)

I found an [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/309154/101063) from [Andy aka](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/20218/andy-aka) with a schematic of the FS1000A transmitter:

[image]

Which shows the the serial input to the FS1000A just turns a 433.92MHz oscillator on or off to modulate the transmitter output.

For the CC1101 to receive the data from a FS1000A, then the CC1101 will need to be configured:

1. The Mode in the `MOD_FORMAT` of the `MDMCFG2` modem configuration register set to On-Off Keying (OOK).
2. The 24-bit frequency word in the `FREQ2`, `FREQ1`, and `FREQ0` registers set to 433.92MHz.
3. Set to Asynchronous Serial Operation, since the the FS1000A just uses the serial input from MCU to modulate the transmitter using OOK without any packet handling capability. Section 27.1 of the CC1101 datasheet explains this will cause the raw receive data to be output:

   > Asynchronous transfer is included in the CC1101 for backward compatibility with systems that are already using the asynchronous data transfer.
   >
   > When asynchronous transfer is enabled, several of the support mechanisms for the MCU that are included in CC1101 will be disabled, such as packet handling hardware, buffering in the FIFO, and so on. The asynchronous transfer mode does not allow for the use of the data whitener, interleaver, and FEC, and it is not possible to use Manchester encoding. MSK is not supported for asynchronous transfer.
   >
   > In asynchronous serial mode no data decision is done on-chip and the raw data is put on the data output line in RX. When using asynchronous serial mode make sure the interfacing MCU does proper oversampling and that it can handle the jitter on the data output line. The MCU should tolerate a jitter of ±1/8 of a bit period as the data stream is timediscrete using 8 samples per bit.
4. Set the `MDMCFG3.DRATE_M` and `MDMCFG4.DRATE_E` configuration registers for a data rate which is compatible with the baud rate used by input to the FS1000A transmitter and the C1101. The limits are:

   - Maximum transfer rate supported by the FS1000A is 10 Kbps
   - Minimum supported by the C1101 is 0.6 Kbps.

The question says the ELECHOUSE_CC1101.h library is being used to program the CC1101. Looking at the [ELECHOUSE_CC1101::RegConfigSettings](https://github.com/simonmonk/CC1101_arduino/blob/master/ELECHOUSE_CC1101.cpp#L282) function:

- There is already code to support setting the RF frequency to 433 MHz via `F_433`
- The `MDMCFG2` modem configuration register is set to the fixed value of `0x03`. I.e. the `MOD_FORMAT` in the register bits `[6:4]` are set to `b000` which means a modulation format of 2-FSK.
- The `ELECHOUSE_CC1101::RegConfigSettings` function currently only allows the RF frequency to be changed from input arguments, and the rest of the CC1101 configuration registers are set to hard coded values.

To answer the question, it should be possible to configure the CC1101 in *Asynchronous Serial Operation* to receive the output from the FS1000A transmitter. However, the ELECHOUSE_CC1101.h library will need some changes as outlined above. I haven't attempted to define all the changes required, but hopefully this answer provides some guidance on the software changes needed.