Connection of FS1000A with CC1101 on the ESP8266 board
I have a problem receiving data from the transmitter. Packets are sent and the receiver registers them. But the data is empty.
The transmitter and receiver are connected to ESP8266 + NodeMCU V3. Two separate devices

The transmitter is the simplest sensor FS1000A.

TX technical data:

Supply voltage: 3.5V - 12V
Transmission speed: up to 9.6 Kb
Operating frequency: 433 MHz
Modulation: AM ASK/OOK
Power: 10mW

TX code (FS1000A)
#include <Wire.h>

#define SENSOR_PIN 16

const int TX_NUMBER = 11887717;

RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(SENSOR_PIN, INPUT);

  mySwitch.enableTransmit(TX_PIN);
  mySwitch.setPulseLength(320);
}

void loop() {
  sendAlert();
  delay(250);
}

void sendAlert() {
  Serial.println("SEND!!");
  mySwitch.send(TX_NUMBER, 24);
}

The receiver is CC1101:
RX code (CC1101)

#include <ELECHOUSE_CC1101_SRC_DRV.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int gdo0 = 5;  // for ESP8266! GDO0 on pin 5 = D1.
  if (ELECHOUSE_cc1101.getCC1101()) {
    Serial.println("Connection OK");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Connection Error");
  }

  ELECHOUSE_cc1101.Init();               
  ELECHOUSE_cc1101.setGDO0(gdo0);
  
  ELECHOUSE_cc1101.setMHZ(433.92);         
  ELECHOUSE_cc1101.SpiWriteReg(CC1101_MDMCFG2, 0x30);
  ELECHOUSE_cc1101.SpiWriteReg(CC1101_MDMCFG4, 0xC8);
  ELECHOUSE_cc1101.SpiWriteReg(CC1101_MDMCFG3, 0x83);
  ELECHOUSE_cc1101.SpiWriteReg(CC1101_PKTCTRL0, 0x32);
  
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Rx Mode");
}

void loop() {
  if (ELECHOUSE_cc1101.CheckReceiveFlag()) {
    byte buffer[64];
    byte length = ELECHOUSE_cc1101.ReceiveData(buffer);

    Serial.print("Length: ");
    Serial.println(length);

    Serial.print("Received: ");
    if (length > 0) {
      for (byte i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Serial.print(buffer[i], HEX);
        Serial.print(" ");
      }
      Serial.println();
    } else {
      Serial.println("No data");
    }

    int rssi = ELECHOUSE_cc1101.getRssi();
    Serial.print("RSSI: ");
    Serial.println(rssi);

    // Debugging received data
    if (length > 0) {
      for (byte i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Serial.print("Byte ");
        Serial.print(i);
        Serial.print(": ");
        Serial.println(buffer[i], BIN); // Display as binary
      }
    }

    
    byte pktstatus = ELECHOUSE_cc1101.SpiReadStatus(CC1101_PKTSTATUS);
    Serial.print("PKTSTATUS: ");
    Serial.println(pktstatus, BIN);

    Serial.print("CRC_OK: ");
    Serial.println((pktstatus & 0x80) != 0);
    Serial.print("CS: ");
    Serial.println((pktstatus & 0x40) != 0);
    Serial.print("CRL: ");
    Serial.println((pktstatus & 0x20) != 0);
    Serial.print("RX_BYTE_OK: ");
    Serial.println((pktstatus & 0x10) != 0);
    Serial.print("RX_BYTE: ");
    Serial.println((pktstatus & 0x08) != 0);
    Serial.print("PKT_L: ");
    Serial.println((pktstatus & 0x04) != 0);

    delay(250);
  }
  delay(100);
}

The receiver registers packets but they are empty. And I would like to read the data in this form "11887717". I've tried various configurations but nothing helped. I am a beginner Arduino programmer. Please give me some tips or correct configuration for the receiver.
This is a preview of the serial port and what the receiver returns:
Connection OK
Rx Mode
Length: 0
Received: No data
RSSI: -25
PKTSTATUS: 11100000
CRC_OK: 1
CS: 1
CRL: 1
RX_BYTE_OK: 0
RX_BYTE: 0
PKT_L: 0


are those two modules even compatible? ... looks like you have the wrong receiver ... use two of the CC1101

The receiver is CC1101 and the transmitter is FS1000A. The receiver can operate with the same frequency and rate as the transmitter. So I think they are compatible. The signal is received, but the packets are empty. I think it's something with the receiver settings, or something between the two libraries.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/700050/can-i-use-a-cc1101-to-read-communication-from-an-fs1000a-transmitter

The C1101 as many HF devices is very susceptible to ESD, because the antenna is not insulated, if you haven't handled the module with care (ESD armband, etc.) it might as well be that the Chip is damaged and does not work properly anymore.
In my experience, even when handling these Modules with all possible Safety equipment they sometimes turn out to be damaged and don't work. The only way to find out if they work is to use code that worked in the past and plug in the newly ordered modules.
I would recommend using the RadioLib by Jan Gromes, because it has served me quite well in the past, but you have to set the pins where you connect the module to custom ones if you don't use an Arduino Uno or similar.
Just as a side note: In total, I ordered about a dozen of these modules within the last year and I had to send back 4 of them because they weren't working properly.
