# Generic 433MHz receiver, how to derive output signal voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, rf, 433mhz

I have a 433MHz receiver modules (Model number MX-05V) The input voltage is listed as 5V but they don't list the output voltage.

I have seen this used without level shifting in a project in conjunction with an ESP32 module that requires 3.3v signals.

In researching how this was safe I found an answer that suggested that the output voltage would be input/2 but I'm unsure how this or why this is.
Unfortunately the answer didn't provide detail, it just happened to mention it in passing.
(https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/103357/274778)

In short, my question is in two parts:
**What** is the signal HIGH voltage (in theory ~2.5v?) for this receiver?
**Why** is it that?

Below is the schematic for the part and a link to a product listing for it, note that on the listing the schematics are labelled backwards.

It's listed as a superhetrodyne receiver and what I take to be the output circuit makes use of a duel opamp (LM 358) but my understanding is too flakey to derive the output voltage from this arrangement.

[image: The schematic for the part]

Links to example of part:
https://hobbycomponents.com/wired-wireless/1054-433mhz-transmitter-receiver-modules-with-antenna
https://hobbycomponents.com/wired-wireless/615-433mhz-wireless-receiver-module-mx-05

Comment: Can't tell you from the schematic, not correct/detailed enough. Can't tell you from the datasheet, not linked. SO, impossible to answer. The one thing I can say with relatively certainty is that whoever called this a "superheterodyne receiver" on the hobbycomponents.com website has *a lot* of explaining to do, and that this is by far the worst schematic I've seen this year.

Comment: Like, literally, is this *actually* the schematic to the circuit you've bought? is there really a 15 pF capacitor in series with a 2700 pF, or did they just show parasitic capacitances here? That would explain C4 and C10, which are impractically low for discrete components...

Comment: Anyway, it's really the job of whoever builds or sells modules to specify what they do. So, vote to close as lacking necessary datasheets.

Comment: Superregenerative receiver. not superheterodyne. They may have meant the average output, or DC component of the output, is 2.5V as these things tend to produce random 0V/5V pulses in the absence of good input signals.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you on both of those points.
Unfortunately I've not been able to find a datasheet or better schematic for this as it's a generic part made by a seemingly endless number of companies without an obvious original name brand.
I'm not even sure of how to describe the circuit well enough to find a similar design with a schematic of a better grade.

Comment: well, then it's not the part you should be using. (sorry for being so harsh! It's just a bit unfair that there's hundreds of sellers of this stuff, and they rely on others to even give basic info on their devices)

Comment: @MarcusMüller
Thanks, harsh but true, I agree. Like a lot of these hobbyist modules It's not held to very high standard of production.
A quick search for 433Mhz module esp/arduino will show up a fair few blogs and guides where it's used.
There's not really an obvious alternative in the hobby bracket.

Comment: It seems like based on @BrianDrummond's comment that my answer is "It can't do it safely".
Perhaps the project I've seen using it has just been getting away with it so far.

It seems I'll need to build a level shifter in or look into alternative modules, I've seen a few that use remote decoder ICs, they wouldn't be interface compatible with this but I can probably make it work.

Comment: nothing to do with standard of production! It's about the quality of sales. Just like a pharmacy can sell the highest quality of medicine, but if you ask them "against what do I take this medicine you're selling me, and what are its side effects", then that pharmacy is a bad pharmacy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the output circuit makes use of a duel opamp (LM 358) but my
> understanding is too flakey to derive the output voltage from this
> arrangement.

[LM358 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358-n.pdf?ts=1611366714979) page 10:-

[image]

This tells you that maximum output voltage is Vcc - ~1.2 V = ~3.8V with 5 V supply. The ESP8266's rated maximum I/O input voltage is 3.6 V, however it probably has protection diodes that don't start conducting until pin voltage goes ~0.6 V above the power supply voltage, ie. 3.3 + 0.6 = 3.9 V.

So people who are using this combination without level shifting are *just* getting away with it *if* the power supply voltages are accurate. To be safe you should lower the output voltage by at least 0.5 V using eg. a voltage divider made from two resistors.

Answer (score 1):

Junction C5 and C6 connects to the base of transistor Q2 who does double duty as oscillator and audio stage.

That would explain C4 and C10, which are impractically low for discrete components.. really?
lol I have .5pf and 1 pf in my junk box... 2pf (2.2pf) is a very common value used in UHF and microwave circuitry.

John

[image]

Comment: There is a detail analysis of the circuit in this video starting at 10:10:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sfx0v42rD40&t=10m10s