# Bypassing Arduino microcontroller to send HIGH and LOW signals for RF module

Tags: rf

I am using [this super cheap and inexpensive Arduino RF module.](https://iotdesignpro.com/projects/rf-communication-between-arduino-using-rf-modules#:%7E:text=RF%20Communication%20between%20Arduino%20using%20RF%20Modules%20The,hence%20consumes%20only%20low%20power%20in%20battery%20operation.)

I know that if I plug it into my Arduino Mega and send the transmitter a 1, it will read HIGH and start transmitting to the receiver. I want the receiver to switch a relay which turns on an accessory.

Instead of plugging it in to an Arduino, I want to have a battery that I hook up to a switch so whenever I throw the manual switch, it sends 5V (HIGH) to the transmitter turning it on, which then sends a signal to the receiver.

Now when the receiver gets this signal, supposedly it outputs a 1 or HIGH or 5V from it's data pin. I wanted to hook this up to the signal wire on the relay to see if that could throw the relay and turn on my accessory hooked to a car battery. In theory I thought this would work.

Unfortunately, it did not work. My circuit diagram is given below.

Let me know if there is something I am blatantly missing or if you agree with my thinking process.

Here is the schematic of my design:

[image: Schematic]

Comment: It more has to do with what is going on internally in an arduino. I want to replicate the HIGH input and output that would happen through an arduino microcontroller, but without it.

Comment: You are not allowed to do what you want. You are only allowed to send short bursts of data on 433MHz, not a constant 1.

Comment: wont the amplitude of the modulated signal just remain the same as the carrier wave amplitude if the input stays high?

Comment: The pins where you want to use a simple HIGH and LOW is called DATA and it is infact a data input / output pin, so treat it as such, feed it with data, not battery.

Comment: but isnt data perceived as high for 5v and low for 0v for 1's and 0's? There is no way that it will be able to read the voltage and as 5V and know its high or read as 0V and know its low?

Comment: No. Apart from voltage level "data" means protocol, timing, codes and alike.

Comment: @Nino roger, thank you

Answer (score 5):

This won't work because your receiver is not designed to work with a continuous carrier wave only.

[Here's](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/544317/generic-433mhz-receiver-how-to-derive-output-signal-voltage) a typical circuit of a superregenerative 433MHz receiver like yours:-

[image]

The demodulated signal is amplified at audio frequency with op amp U1:B, AC coupled via capacitors C8 and C10 (ringed in red). U1:A squares up the signal by operating as a comparator with a small amount of hysteresis. If you send a '1' continuously (carrier permanently on) the CN2 output *may* stay at '1' provided there is no noise in the signal, but when you send a '0' (no carrier) the receiver will wind its gain up trying to get a signal until it outputs continuous noise.

The upshot of this is that you have to send a series of pulses at audio frequency, with two different 'patterns' (eg. different frequencies, pulse widths, or digital codes) - representing On and Off commands to the relay - then detect these states with an external device such as an MCU or dedicated remote decoder IC. When not sending anything the decoder must be able to reject the noise that comes out of the receiver, which means a simple frequency discriminator or pulse width detector won't work reliably. Some kind of error detection is required.

An example of a dedicated decoder IC is the [HT12D](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/57850.pdf), which together with its companion [HT12E](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1899539.pdf) encoder IC is commonly used in 'key fob' type remote control systems designed for garage door openers etc. These are available as bare chips, or combined with the 433MHz transmitter and receiver to make a complete remote control set.

The HT12D has latched outputs which hold their state after a button press. You should use this rather than a non-latching decoder such as the HT12F because 433MHz transmissions are not supposed to be sent continuously, to prevent interfering with other remote controls on the same frequency.

Also realize that most decoders do have not enough output current to operate a relay directly, so will probably need a driver transistor. Relay modules are available which have the driver transistor built in.